# Can we store java.util.concurrent.Future values in a Global variable? Is that correct way?

Tags: java

My testNg test1 will call the `executor.submit(callable);` the responsibility of that callable is to trigger a action and i ll store it in `List<Future<T>>` and i have declared that `List<Future<T>>` as Global variable.And my second TestNg test will pick it and it will call `Future.get()` and it will display the result.

can anyone help me!

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class test1 {

    public static final List<Future<Boolean>> callBackList = new ArrayList<>();

    @DataProvider(name = "HappyTestCases")
    protected Iterator<Object[]> getHappyTestCases(){
        List<Integer> inputTestDataIntValue = new ArrayList<>();
        inputTestDataIntValue.add(1);
        inputTestDataIntValue.add(2);
        inputTestDataIntValue.add(3);
        inputTestDataIntValue.add(4);
        inputTestDataIntValue.add(5);
        inputTestDataIntValue.add(6);
        inputTestDataIntValue.add(7);
        inputTestDataIntValue.add(8);
        inputTestDataIntValue.add(9);
        inputTestDataIntValue.add(10);
        List<Object[]> testCasesAsObjectArray = inputTestDataIntValue.stream().map(testCaseObj -> new Object[]{testCaseObj})
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return testCasesAsObjectArray.iterator();
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "callBackCases")
    protected Iterator<Object[]> getcallBackCases(){
        List<Object[]> testCasesAsObjectArray = callBackList.stream().map(testCaseObj -> new Object[]{testCaseObj})
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return testCasesAsObjectArray.iterator();
    }

    @org.testng.annotations.Test(dataProvider = "HappyTestCases")
    public void runTestNgTest(Integer data) throws Exception {
        RunInitiator(Arrays.asList(data));     
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "HappyTestCases")
    public void runCallBackList(Future<Boolean> callback) throws Exception{

     List<Boolean> reslutList = runCallBack(Arrays.asList(callback));

        for(Boolean b : reslutList) {
            if(b) {
                System.out.println("TestCase passed for testCase Id: ");
            }else {
                System.out.println("TestCase failed for testCase Id: ");
            }
        }
    }

    public void RunInitiator(List<Integer> inputTestDataIntValue) throws Exception {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        for(Integer integer : inputTestDataIntValue) {
            System.out.println("intValue = " + integer);
            System.out.println("executor is going to start");
            Future<Boolean> callBack = executor.submit(new Task(integer));
            System.out.println("Thread Name = "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
            callBackList.add(callBack);
        }

        System.out.println("successfully finished runIntiator");
    }

    public List<Boolean> runCallBack(List<Future<Boolean>> callBackList) throws Exception{
        List<Boolean> resultList = Lists.newArrayList();
        //iterate and give it to different test.
        for(Future<Boolean> callBack : callBackList) {
            Boolean result = callBack.get();
            resultList.add(result);
            System.out.println("result = "+ result);
        }

        return resultList;

    }

    static class Task implements Callable<Boolean> {

        public Integer intValue;

        public Task(int intValue) {
            this.intValue = intValue;
        }

        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Thread Name inside callable = " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("Sleeping for 2mins");
            Thread.sleep(120000);
            if (intValue < 5) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you?  Sure.  It seems implied (and in the case of `get()` explicitly stated) that `Future` is thread safe.  Should you?  Dunno, global variables are frown upon for a reason.

Comment: *"Can we store java.util.concurrent.Future values in a Global variable?"* ... more often than not, when you're working with Java and the question which you're asking contains the phrase "global variable", the best possible answer is usually, "you're better off with a different approach or design strategy."

Comment: TestNg makes /one/ test case implementation object, and re-uses it for every test.  So it can just be a member variable.   It will even call the special methods annotated with `@BeforeClass` after creating the object and before testing, so that you can initialize variables that all of your test cases will share.